# Controlling multiple GoPros using separate network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, gopro

My objective is be able to control multiple GoPro cameras using one board and different network interfaces on the board itself. The problem I am facing is that each camera options it's functions under 10.5.5.9 which I assume is unique per interface since they're on different interfaces, but that is not the case (go easy, I'm new to this). When I follow the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996494/send-http-request-through-specific-network-interface), it will send the request to one interface but it doesn't seem to switch to the other interface (only one camera activates).

[Ifconfig Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jghup.png)

This is a screen of my original `ifconfig` before I try to do route configuration. `wlan0` has an inet of `10.5.5.100` and `wlan1` has an inet of `10.5.5.102`. Following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/643127/seting-up-iptables-to-forward-multiple-gopro-cameras) solution, I try to configure each interface, but that is either outdated or I did something wrong because both of my interfaces have an inet of 10.5.5.9 - when I try to send a curl request to either interface, I get a response of "curl (7) Failed to connect to 10.5.5.9 port 80: Connection refuse" and the same when I send a request the original inet of the interface.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pictures of screen shots is not ideal.  its best to highlight the information copy and paste it. you should be able to right click and copy, if not you can use CTRL+INSERT then paste it in your question.   It's also best to include the specific commands you type.  I believe your issue is that you want to change the IP address of the cameras so they are unique.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning both network interfaces to the same network. The netmask of 255.255.255.0 means that this network handles the addresses beginning with 10.5.5. Hence - your 10.5.5.9 address can be reached by both interfaces, causing a clash. If the addresses of your GoPros are statically assigned and cannot be changed, two network interfaces will not help. I can't see any possibility to solve this without changing at least one GoPro IP.